# Spring Java Config. Use of PropertiesFactoryBean in the configuration file

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, external

I've the following configuration file

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.foo")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppSpringConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Value("#{cvlExternalProperties['dbDriverClassName']}")
    private String dbDriverName;

    @Bean
    public PropertiesFactoryBean cvlExternalProperties() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean res = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        res.setFileEncoding("UTF-8");
        res.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(env.resolvePlaceholders("${MY_ENV_VAR}") + "external.properties"));
        return res;
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicDataSource datasource() {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("myDriverClassName");
        basicDataSource.setUrl("MyDbUrl");
        basicDataSource.setUsername("myUser");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("myPass");
        return basicDataSource;
    }
}
```

And in the external properties file I've

```
dbUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/someDb
dbUser=someUser
dbPassword=somePass
dbDriverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

In which way I can use the cvlProperties inside the datasource() method?
I've tried

```
env.getProperty("dbDriverClassName")
env.getProperty("#cvlProperties['dbDriverClassName']")
```

But I'm not able to retrieve the properties.
The field dbDriverName is correctly filled, so that means the bean declaration is ok.
I want to use the PropertyFactoryBean class because in this way I can specify the encoding to use.

If I use the the following annotation on the top of the configuration class

```
@PropertySource("file:${MY_ENV_VAR}/external.properties")
```

I'm able to retrieve the properties with this piece of code

```
env.getProperty("dbDriverClassName")
```

But the encoding used by the PropertySource annotation is the windows default, and for me is not correct.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment the solution(that I don't love so much) is to declare the properties by using the annotation @Value

```
@Value("#{cvlExternalProperties['dbDriverClassName']}")
private String dbDriverClassName;
```

and then using it inside the java class